# Need to parse a Json object and append it to a table

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var abc, obj, i, j;
            abc = {
                "cars": [
                    '{"model":"Sentra", "doors":4, "lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]}',
                    '{"model":"Maxima", "doors":4,"lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]}',
                    '{"model":"Skyline", "doors":2,"lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]}'
                ]
            }
            var obj = JSON.parse(abc);
            var theader = "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>year</th></tr>";
            document.getElementById("dtable").appendChild(theader);
            var x;
            for (i = 0; i < abc.cars.length; i++) {
                x += "<tr><td>" + obj.cars[i].model + "</td><td>" + obj.cars[i].doors + "</td><td>" + obj.cars[i].lol[0] + "</td></tr>";
                document.getElementById("dtable").appendChild(x);
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ,id="dsjson">
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">display json</button>
        <br><br>
        <table id="dtable"></table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The nested json data needs to be displayed in the HTML table. On clicking the button the table displaying the json must appear. We can use JavaScript or JQuery For that one. In my example, I am using JavaScript. I don't know where it's going wrong.

Comment: `abc.cars` is an Array of Strings in your example. I'm pretty sure you should have started with an Array of Objects.

Comment: i meant to use three json objects of the type car. could you help correct this? @StackSlave

Comment: Take the single quotes off of `' {"model":"Sentra", "doors":4, "lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]}'` and the like, so it's just `{"model":"Sentra", "doors":4, "lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]}`. Of course, don't `JSON.parse` then. Did you create that `abc` data manually, or did it really come from a database?

Comment: No need of JSON.Parse in this method.You can access this object like this "abc.cars[i].doors".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have few issues in your code.

First of all `appendChild()` accepts a dom node as the parameter but you are providing htmlString, try `insertAdjacentHTML()` OR `innerHTML` instead.

Then you are modifying the DOM  inside the loop with the previous value, this will duplicate the result.

You can try the following way:

```js
function myFunction(){
  var abc,i,j;
  var abc = {
  "cars": [
      {"model":"Sentra", "doors":4, "lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]},
      {"model":"Maxima", "doors":4,"lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]},
      {"model":"Skyline", "doors":2,"lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]}
    ]
  };
  var theader = "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>year</th></tr>";
  document.getElementById("dtable").innerHTML = theader;
  var x ='';
  for (i=0; i <  abc.cars.length; i++) {
    x += "<tr><td>" + abc.cars[i].model + "</td><td>" + abc.cars[i].doors+ "</td><td>" + abc.cars[i].lol[0]+ "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("dtable").innerHTML += x;
};
```

```html
<div class ="container" id = "dsjson">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">display json</button>
  <br><br>
  <table id="dtable"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jacob, `appendChild()` adds a node (not htmlString) but `innerHTML`  gets or sets the htmlString.:)

Comment: Not sure why you are telling me this on this answer? Also, you have not offered any explanation to OP about where they have gone wrong and how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to parse abc since it is already an object, but you need to parse each car object

````
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction(){
var abc,obj,i,j;
abc = 
    {"cars": [

           ' {"model":"Sentra", "doors":4, "lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]}',
            '{"model":"Maxima", "doors":4,"lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]}',
            '{"model":"Skyline", "doors":2,"lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]}'



]}
var obj = abc;
var theader = "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>year</th></tr>";
document.getElementById("dtable").appendChild(theader);
var x;
for (i=0; i <  abc.cars.length; i++) {
    abc.cars[i]=JSON.parse(abc.cars[i]);
  x += "<tr><td>" + obj.cars[i].model + "</td><td>" + obj.cars[i].doors+ "</td><td>" + obj.cars[i].lol[0]+ "</td></tr>"  ;
document.getElementById("dtable").appendChild(x);

}

};


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class ="container" ,id = "dsjson">

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">display json</button>
<br><br>
<table id="dtable"></table>
</div>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already an object. No need to parse it. The javascript interpreter has already parsed it for you.

If you want to add content using html strings, you can use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) in Vanilla.js

```js
const dtable = document.getElementById("dtable");
const obj = {
  "cars": [{
      "model": "Sentra",
      "doors": 4,
      "lol": [
        "hi",
        "hello",
        "hahahaha"
      ]
    },
    {
      "model": "Maxima",
      "doors": 4,
      "lol": [
        "hi",
        "hello",
        "hahahaha"
      ]
    },
    {
      "model": "Skyline",
      "doors": 2,
      "lol": [
        "hi",
        "hello",
        "hahahaha"
      ]
    }
  ]
};
const cars = obj.cars;
const theader = "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>year</th></tr>";

function myFunction() {
  for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      dtable.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', theader);
    }
    let row = `<tr>
    <td>${cars[i].model}</td>
    <td>${cars[i].doors}</td>
    <td>${cars[i].lol[0]}</td>
    </tr>`;
    dtable.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', row);
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" ,id="dsjson">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">display json</button>
    <br><br>
    <table id="dtable"></table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use some JSON validator tools like https://jsonlint.com/ or similar.

Now no need for `abc` var.

```
var obj = {
  cars: [
    {
      model: "Sentra",
      doors: 4,
      lol: ["hi", "hello", "hahahaha"]
    },
    {
      model: "Maxima",
      doors: 4,
      lol: ["hi", "hello", "hahahaha"]
    },
    {
      model: "Skyline",
      doors: 2,
      lol: ["hi", "hello", "hahahaha"]
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are a bit confused with `appendChild` and `innerHTML`.

If you want to use `appendChild` you will need to provide an HTML element, however, if you just want to add HTML text, use `innerHTML`.

`abc` is already a JSON object, so you don't need to parse it again, however, you will want to parse the `lol` prop inside.

Here are those changes and some small improvements, using object destructuring to clean some things up a little.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
      var abc, obj, i, j;
      abc = {
        "cars": [
          '{"model":"Sentra", "doors":4, "lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]}',
          '{"model":"Maxima", "doors":4,"lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]}',
          '{"model":"Skyline", "doors":2,"lol":["hi","hello","hahahaha"]}'
        ]
      }

      var theader = "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>year</th></tr>";
      document.getElementById("dtable").innerHTML = (theader);
      var x = "";
      for (i = 0; i < abc.cars.length; i++) {
        const car = JSON.parse(abc.cars[i])
        const { model, doors, lol } = car
        x += "<tr><td>" + model + "</td><td>" + doors + "</td><td>" + lol[0] + "</td></tr>";
      }
      document.getElementById("dtable").innerHTML += x;
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" ,id="dsjson">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">display json</button>
    <br><br>
    <table id="dtable"></table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are asking me the difference between `appendChild()` and `innerHTML` and posting the answer here!!!

Comment: @Mamun sorry, I don't follow what your asking? Im not using appendChild?